# Send message to WebSocket server from a PHP Webhook

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

I have a websocket server working and I need to connect a webhook to it, so I can send updates to clients connected to that websocket whenever the PHP webhook receives updates via POST.

Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, there are websocket client libraries for PHP which should make it easier for you to make a connection and send a message from the PHP script. Have you done any research? Where are you stuck?

Comment: So I’m using ratchet and everything works fine, but now I need to integrate with the web hook I made for the WhatsApp business api, so that when the web hook receives updates, it sends a “signal” to the websocket server informing what client should have the conversation page refreshed.

Comment: Ok yes I understand. My first comment described that it's possible (as you asked) and that you can likely find tools you help you do this, if you do some simple research online.

Comment: Have a look at  https://github.com/napengam/phpWebSocketServer
in the directroy  phpClient you might find some code. In the 
directory websocketExtern you see examples on usage.